# Confusion in Spark's partitioning strategy on dataFrames

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

In the following I am getting the same number of partitions (200) in all the four print statements. The initial dataframe (df1) is partitioned on 4 columns `(account_id, schema_name, table_name, column_name)`. But the subsequent dataframes are partitioned only on 3 fields `(account_id, schema_name, table_name)`. Can someone please explain to me, if Spark is able to retain the partitioning strategy from step1-step4 and doesn't need to shuffle the data anymore after step1.

```
val query1: String = "SELECT account_id, schema_name, table_name, 
column_name, COLLECT_SET(u.query_id) AS query_id_set FROM usage_tab 
GROUP BY account_id, schema_name, table_name, column_name"
val df1 = session.sql(query1)
println("1 " + df.rdd.getNumPartitions)


df1.createOrReplaceTempView("wtftempusage")
val query2 = "SELECT DISTINCT account_id, schema_name, table_name 
FROM wtftempusage"
val df2 = session.sql(query2)
println("2 " + df2.rdd.getNumPartitions)


//MyFuncIterator retains all columns for df2 and adds an additional column
val extendedDF = df2.mapPartitions(MyFuncIterator)
println("3 " + extendedDF.rdd.getNumPartitions)


val joinedDF = df1.join(extendedDF, Seq("account_id", "schema_name", "table_name"))
println("4 " + joinedDF.rdd.getNumPartitions)
```

Thanks,
Devj

Answer (score 0):

The default number of shuffle partitions in DF API is 200.

You can Set the default shuffle.partitons to a lesser number. Say like: 
sqlContext.setConf ("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions","5")

Comment: You can also specify the number of partitions for a shuffle operation e.g.
`rdd.reduceByKey(lambda x, y: x+y, numPartitions=400)`

Comment: Got it. But my other question is that, whether there will be a shuffle in step (2) and (3), Or Spark will be able to figure out that the data is already partitioned.